# Syncing MBProgressHUD Through Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, mbprogresshud

This question may seem a little redundant in the forums, but I have not been able to come to a conclusion after a good deal of searching and I hope I will find my answer here.

I am having a problem using MBProgressHUD. I am using two view controllers. **Controller A** and **Controller B**.

I am also using a segue to transfer parsed data from **A** to **B**. I have tried putting the MBProgressHUD before the segue, but the progress bar doesn't show up until it reaches **Controller B**. I need to figure out a way to either thread it in the background or use it asynchronously.

**Question:** *How do I have the MBProgressHUD load during the segue from **Controller A** to **Controller** B?*

1. Initiate Segue, and MBProgressHUD
2. MBProgressHUD runs in background of **Controller A** while transferring parsed data to **Controller B**
3. When it finally segues and reaches **Controller B**, MBProgressHUD stops.

For reference, this is an excerpt of my prepareForSegue method.

Thanks in advance.

```
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    currentStore = [arrayOfStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    ReportsViewController *destinationVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    destinationVC.name = self.selectedCellName;
    destinationVC.startDate = selectedStartDate;
    destinationVC.endDate = selectedEndDate;
    destinationVC.netSales = currentStore.netSales;
    destinationVC.voids = currentStore.voids;
    destinationVC.discounts = currentStore.discounts;
    destinationVC.guestCount = currentStore.guestCount;
    destinationVC.peopleServed = currentStore.peopleServed;
    destinationVC.employeeClockIn = currentStore.employeesClock;
```

Comment: Can you put where are you showing the HUD?

Comment: @iphonic I'm not quite sure where to put it, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfect for me. I just dispatched the segue and threw the MBProgressHUD afterwards.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("Camaleon Reports", NULL);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"report" sender:nil];

            });
        });

[self loadingData];
```